# CUDA struct encapsulating static 2D object

Tags: c, arrays, struct, cuda, 2d

When I create a struct with a 3-deep struct and the deepest level has a 2 diminsional array, allocating the memory on the device and accessing that array causes a memory checker access violation error when using the CUDA debugger.  Here is an example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
} Level3;

typedef struct {
    Level3 lvl3ObjArr[10][10];
} Level2;

typedef struct {
    Level2 lvl2Obj;
} Level1;

__global__ void AccessViolationKernel(Level1 *_lvl1Ptr)
{
    int _value;

    _lvl1Ptr->lvl2Obj.lvl3ObjArr[2][5].value = 4;
    _value = _lvl1Ptr->lvl2Obj.lvl3ObjArr[2][5].value;

    printf("Value = %i\n", _value);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Level1 *lvl1Ptr;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&lvl1Ptr, sizeof(Level1));
    AccessViolationKernel<<<5, 1>>>(lvl1Ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Even looking at the memory and adding the correct bytes, everything seems to add up correctly for the lvl1Ptr's encapsulated reference to lvl3ObjArr[2][5] when using the CUDA debugger.  Still, the data accessed is incorrect and the memchecker throws an access violation.

Is Level1 not allocated correctly on the device?  Why am I getting an access violation?

Thanks in advance!

-- UPDATE (9/30/2013 16:29PM CST) --

This code compiles (sorry!) but it doesn't exhibit the error.  I think its because instead of cudaMalloc I'm using the device API malloc instead, and attempting to access the data later from the host's CUDA API.  It will take a while for me to generate the code to reproduce this, my apologies--the source code I'm reducing is 2800 lines long.

Comment: Could you post actual code that could be compiled?

Comment: Simply confirming that the code you have posted at the moment appears to be valid, runs correctly, and gives expected printout.  `cuda-memcheck` reports no errors.  If you are using device `malloc`, you cannot access memory allocated that way using the runtime API.  Instead, you would first need to copy the data from that region to a region that has been allocated already using e.g. `cudaMalloc`, then copy that data to the host.

Comment: Robert, thanks again for your help.  I seem to still be having latent issues mixing the host CUDA API and device kernel mallocs.  The odd thing is I allocate the first level object in my large code set, using cudaMalloc, and access one of the buried 2D object array's values and I get a singular access violation.  It only happens when I access the deepest values, not when I access the pointers in the buried structures referencing and dereferencing to get to that buried value.  When I find the solution or a reduced version of the code that exhibits the same error, I will repost.

Comment: Ok, found the solution.  I was mixing cudaMalloc with malloc/free in a kernel... of course.  It wasn't intuitive because I was allocating the root with cudaMalloc, and later on allocating it again on the device with malloc.  Some objects remained allocated from the host, so the device heap was unaware during access, and would throw an access violation.

Comment: Please provide your comments as an answer so that we can call this an answered question.  Or else delete the question -- it serves no purpose as-is, and no one else can answer it, since you haven't provided any code that shows an error.   Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'm new to SO (as soon as I figure out how).  I'll delete this, the answer is misleading to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution. I was mixing cudaMalloc with malloc/free in a kernel. It wasn't intuitive because I was allocating the root with cudaMalloc, and later on allocating it again on the device with malloc. Some objects remained allocated from the host via encapsulation, so the device heap was unaware during access, and would throw an access violation.